# AdMob Interstitial ads display after app closed

Tags: java, android

I have an application and I added Interstitial ads and made it display many times. but the problem that it don't display until the app finish.

example:
I made Interstitial ad display when navigate between to activities. but it will display after the app finish not when navigation as I want.

I have searched a lot about this problem and I didn't found any solution.

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0):

```
**//object creation**
InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

**//oncreate**
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-id");
requestNewInterstitial();

**//button click event**
if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
  mInterstitialAd.show();
}
else {
  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),nextactivity.class);
  startActivity(i);
  finish();
}

mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
  @Override
  public void onAdClosed() {
    requestNewInterstitial();

    **//after add display**
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
        nextactivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();

    **//after oncreate**
    private void requestNewInterstitial() {
      AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("CC5F2C72DF2B356BBF0DA198")
        .build();
      mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thaaanks a lot, you're are genius. My problem was solved.